# Combining Two Queries in to One - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Trying to combine the following two queries which involves negations and ending up with getting removed the required rows as well. If run them separately using the MINUS, I'm getting the required result.

```
 SELECT *
      FROM table1 t1
     WHERE t1.b_c IN ('A', 'B') AND t1.d_id IN ('2', '3')
           AND ( (t1.a_d >= '1-May-2018'AND t1.a_d <= '15-May-2018')
                OR (t1.a_r >= '1-May-2018'  AND t1.a_r <= '15-May-2018'))
           AND (    t1.a_m = 'AC'
                AND t1.s = 'SW'
                AND t1.c_m IN ('DM', 'SW')
                AND t1.d_m IN ('DM', 'SW')
                OR ((t1.a_m = 'NO' AND t1.s = 'SW')
  AND (   (t1.d_m = 'DM' AND t1.c_m = 'DM')
       OR (t1.d_m = 'SW' AND t1.c_m = 'DM')
       OR NOT (t1.d_m = 'DM' AND t1.c_m = 'SW')
       OR (t1.d_m = 'SW' AND t1.c_m = 'SW'))))
           AND ( (t1.a_m,t1.s,t1.d_m,t1.c_m,t1.d_s) NOT IN
  ( ('NO', 'SW', 'SW', 'DM', 'X001'),
   ('NO', 'SW', 'SW', 'DM', 'XXXX')))

    MINUS
    (SELECT *
       FROM table1 t1
      WHERE t1.b_c IN ('A', 'B') AND t1.d_id IN ('2', '3')
            AND ( (t1.a_d >= '1-May-2018' AND t1.a_d <= '15-May-2018')
                 OR (t1.a_r >= '1-May-2018'   AND t1.a_r <= '15-May-2018'))
            AND t1.dept_id IN ('20', '35')
            AND t1.a_m IN ('AC', 'NO')
            AND t1.s = 'SW'
            AND t1.c_m = 'DM'
            AND t1.d_m IN ('DM', 'SW')
            AND ((t1.o_b = 'X001' AND t1.s_s = 'X001' ) OR (t1.o_b = 'XXXX'   AND t1.s_s = 'XXXX'))
            AND REGEXP_LIKE (t1.r_no, '^(20PS|35RE)'))
```

Combined query:

```
SELECT *
  FROM table1 t1
 WHERE t1.b_c IN ('A', 'B') AND t1.d_id IN ('2', '3')
       AND ( (t1.a_d >= '1-May-2018' AND t1.a_d <= '15-May-2018')
            OR (t1.a_r >= '1-May-2018' AND t1.a_r <= '15-May-2018'))
       AND t1.a_m IN ('AC', 'NO')
       AND t1.s = 'SW'
       AND t1.c_m IN ('DM', 'SW')
       AND t1.d_m IN ('DM', 'SW')
       AND (NOT ( ( (t1.a_m, t1.s, t1.d_m, t1.c_m, t1.d_s) IN
                       ( ('NO', 'SW', 'SW', 'DM', 'X001'),
                        ('NO', 'SW', 'SW', 'DM', 'XXXX')))
                 OR ( (t1.s, t1.d_m, t1.c_m) IN ( ('SW', 'DM', 'SW')))
                 OR ( ( (t1.a_m, t1.s, t1.d_m, t1.c_m, t1.o_b, t1.b_b, t1.s_s) IN
                           ( ('AC', 'SW', 'DM', 'DM', 'XXXX', 'X001', 'XXXX'),
                            ('AC', 'SW', 'DM', 'DM', 'X001', 'XXXX', 'X001'))
                       AND REGEXP_LIKE (t1.r_no, '^(20PS|35RE)')))))
```

When I ran the combined query, following required row got removed.

```
t1.a_m t1.s t1.d_m t1.c_m t1.o_b t1.b_b t1.s_s t1.r_no
AC     SW   DM     DM                          35REXXXX
```

Please let me know where i have made the mistake.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: With the information provided, I think nobody except you know what are you talking about

Comment: Add sample input and output, so we all can see what your intent is.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very naive approach, but I think it will work for you.

```
SELECT *
      FROM table1 t1
     WHERE t1.b_c IN ('A', 'B') AND t1.d_id IN ('2', '3')
           AND ( (t1.a_d >= '1-May-2018'AND t1.a_d <= '15-May-2018')
                OR (t1.a_r >= '1-May-2018'  AND t1.a_r <= '15-May-2018'))
           AND (    t1.a_m = 'AC'
                AND t1.s = 'SW'
                AND t1.c_m IN ('DM', 'SW')
                AND t1.d_m IN ('DM', 'SW')
                OR ((t1.a_m = 'NO' AND t1.s = 'SW')
  AND (   (t1.d_m = 'DM' AND t1.c_m = 'DM')
       OR (t1.d_m = 'SW' AND t1.c_m = 'DM')
       OR NOT (t1.d_m = 'DM' AND t1.c_m = 'SW')
       OR (t1.d_m = 'SW' AND t1.c_m = 'SW'))))
           AND ( (t1.a_m,t1.s,t1.d_m,t1.c_m,t1.d_s) NOT IN
  ( ('NO', 'SW', 'SW', 'DM', 'X001'),
   ('NO', 'SW', 'SW', 'DM', 'XXXX')))
  -- added this:
  AND NOT (t1.dept_id IN ('20', '35')
            AND t1.a_m IN ('AC', 'NO')
            AND t1.s = 'SW'
            AND t1.c_m = 'DM'
            AND t1.d_m IN ('DM', 'SW')
            AND ((t1.o_b = 'X001' AND t1.s_s = 'X001' ) OR (t1.o_b = 'XXXX'   AND t1.s_s = 'XXXX'))
            AND REGEXP_LIKE (t1.r_no, '^(20PS|35RE)')))
;
```

I just took the parts of the MINUS'd conditions that were different from the original set, and added them with a NOT.

It's probably possible to further improve this, but without further context it doesn't seem worthwhile.